# Sublime intellisense selects padding-bottom by default and not padding

Tags: sublime-text-2, autocomplete

Much as I love Sublime, something that annoys me is that I cannot figure out how to make it select "padding" or "margin" rather than "padding-bottom" or "margin-bottom" by default.

Is there a way to change this? I would give options of what I have tried but I dont know where to start looking, other than trying to find an answer here on SU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using projects in Sublime.  This saves two config files, Example.sublime-project and Example.sublime-workspace.  The project file saves the project's path and you can add project specific settings in there.  The workspace file, among other settings, saves project autocompletes that Sublime has made based on your previous input.  So at one point, you have typed `padd` (or something to that effect) and then choose `padding-bottom` from the list.  Sublime then decides that whenever you type `padd` then you would like `padding-bottom` as the default.  Sometimes it works out, sometimes it doesn't.  You can manually edit that file and remove the padding-bottom entry, or replace it with padding.

First close the project, or else the file will just be overwritten.

Existing:

```
[
    "padd",
    "padding-bottom"
],
```

Change to:

```
[
    "padd",
    "padding"
],
```

Remove any other padding entries that might take precedence over your chosen option.

Comment: Aaaaah.....fresh air just blew through my door! Thanks D_Rail!